# How to synthesize lanthanum(III) chloride & Cerium(III) chloride from their oxides?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, synthesis

Interested in obtaining anhydrous lanthanum/cerium chlorides

1. $\ce{La2O3}$ / $\ce{СeO2}$ in a flow of carbon tetrachloride at 500 degrees
2. $\ce{La2O3}$ / $\ce{CeO2}$ with ammonium chloride when heated (As I understand it, this method has a problem with the formation of oxochlorides)

Does it practically work? Is there any information? Maybe there is an easier option?

UPD1:
The oxide reaction is not feasible with all oxides, it depends on their production.

I tried this with different concentrations of hydrochloric acid, my cerium oxide sample didn't dissolve.

***Kinetics and mechanism of the reduction-dissolution of cerium oxide catalyzed by fluoride ions in hydrochloric acid solution.***
*The reduction-dissolution of CeO2 in hydrochloric media obeys Eq. (4):
The protocol used here to investigate this reaction has been described previously (Lemont et al., 2015). The experimental setup is shown in Fig. 2. Two types of CeO2 powders were considered, shown previously to react one completely (one supply: CeO2 Acros 99.995% batch n° A011584501) one not at all (three supplies: CeO2 Acros 99.995% batch n° A010849501, CeO2 Alfa 99.995% batch n° 97,077, CeO2*

Comment: 3. Buying it maybe?

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanthanum(III)_chloride) mentions synthesis of $\ce{LaCl3}$ from $\ce{La2O3}$:

> Anhydrous lanthanum(III) chloride can be produced by the ammonium chloride route. In the first step, lanthanum oxide is heated with ammonium chloride to produce the ammonium salt of the pentachloride:
>
> $$\ce{La2O3 + 10 NH4Cl → 2 (NH4)2LaCl5 + 6 H2O + 6 NH3}$$
>
> In the second step, the ammonium chloride salt is converted to the trichlorides by heating in a vacuum at 350-400 ºC:
>
> $$\ce{(NH4)2LaCl5 → LaCl3 + 2 HCl + 2 NH3}$$

As for $\ce{CeCl3}$, refer to this [prepchem article](https://www.prepchem.com/synthesis-of-cerium-trichloride/):

> $$\ce{CeO2 + 4HCl -> CeCl4 + 2H2O}$$
> $$\ce{2CeCl4 ->[\Delta] 2CeCl3 + Cl2}$$
>
> 85 ml of concentrated hydrochloric acid is mixed with 40 ml of water and poured into the 500 ml flask. 48 g of cerium(IV) oxide are added to the solution of hydrochloric acid. The solution is warmed gently until the reaction starts and heated for 5 minutes. When the reaction is complete the solution is filtered and evaporated to 70 ml. The obtained solution is poured into a small crystallizing dish, cover with a watch glass, cooled slowly. The obtained crystals are separated by filtration, and the additional amount could be obtained from the filtrate.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. CeCl3: According to your link, I turned to the source: https://research-solution.com/uplode/book/book-33147.pdf there really is a good recommendation.

LaCl3: I would like to find experience from practice.

Comment: @1st32 if the answer helped you, please make sure to accept it.